# Einstein-Palatini action in $d$-dimensions

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, spacetime-dimensions, action

The [tetradic Einstein-Palatini action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetradic_Palatini_action) can be written as (see, for instance, [arXiv:1804.09685](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.09685))

$$S=\epsilon_{IJKL}\int_{\mathcal{M}}e^I\wedge e^J\wedge\Omega^{KL},$$

where $e^I$ are the frame variables and $\Omega^{IJ}$ is the curvature constructed from the spin connection. Clearly, however, since the $e^I$ are one-forms and the $\Omega^{IJ}$ are two forms, this construction only applies to a four-dimensional manifold.

Are there generalizations of this action that apply in arbitrary dimesions?

Answer (score 3):

Up to a different convention for the Hodge dual expansion, you can consider the action
$$
S=\int \Omega^{IJ}\wedge \star(e_I\wedge e_J)
$$
The integral kernel always has dimension $D$. In four dimensions (with the convention I am using) you will get your result with a 1/2 in front, because 
$$
\star(e_I\wedge e_J)=\dfrac{1}{(D-2)!}\epsilon_{IJK_1\dots K_{D-2}}e^{K_1}\wedge\dots \wedge e^{K_{D-2}}
$$
This is just the $D$-dimensional Einstein-Hilbert action in the language of differential forms.

Comment: Your last equation also only works in $4$-dimensions. I think the thing you meant to write is something like $\star(e_I\wedge e_J)=\frac{1}{(d-2)!}\epsilon_{IJI_3\cdots I_d}e^{I_3}\wedge\cdots e^{I_d}$.

Comment: oooops sorry my mistake, yes you are correct!